# DbContext: usar outras strings de conexão - EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Eu tenho um arquivo `web.config` com 4 strings de conexão. Como eu posso colocar essas strings de conexão na classe `DbContext`?

```
public DataContext():base("ConnectionString") // Essa é minha conexão padrão
{

}
```

Como eu posso fazer o mesmo usando outra conexão?

Comment: Você quer que cada contexto seja inicializado por uma conexão diferente?

Answer (score 2):

Quando você cria as strings de conexão no web.config você passa nomes pra elas na propriedade name. Pra você escolher uma na sua implementação de `DbContext` basta passar para o construtor da classe base o nome da conexão como está na propriedade name no web.config. É como você fez, mas com o nome das outras conexões.

**EDIT:** Um exemplo seria o seguinte, você adiciona no web.config a seguinte string de conexão

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Exemplo" connectionString="ConnectionString" providerName="Provider" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Sendo que `ConnectionString` é sua string de conexão e `Provider` o seu provider, que no caso e SQL Server é `System.Data.SqlClient`. Daí no seu contexto, você faria o seguinte

```
public class ContextoExemplo : DbContext
{
    public ContextoExemplo() : base("Exemplo") {}
}
```

Daí esse contexto vai suar a string de conexão com `name` Exemplo que você adicionou. Cada contexto teria simplesmente que por ali o que vai na propriedade name e o EF sabe que é pra usar *aquela* string de conexão.

Comment: poderia me dar um exemplo.

Comment: @LucasVianaMunhoz, adicionei um exemplo, veja se ajuda.